# How would I tell PS to read a file name and use it?

Tags: windows, powershell

In my script I want PS to read whatever the name of the file is in the "Windows ISO" directory and use that file instead of hard coding the filename "Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso" since that will change over time. How would I do this in the code below?

```
#region MountDismountCopy
# ISO image - replace with path to ISO to be mounted
$isoImg = "C:\ESD\Windows 10 ISO\Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso"
# Drive letter - use desired drive letter
$driveLetter = "Y:"

# Mount the ISO, without having a drive letter auto-assigned
$diskImg = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoImg  -NoDriveLetter

# Get mounted ISO volume
$volInfo = $diskImg | Get-Volume

# Mount volume with specified drive letter (requires Administrator access)
mountvol $driveLetter $volInfo.UniqueId

[string]$sourceDirectory  = "Y:\*"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "C:\ESD\Deployment"
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory

# Unmount drive
DisMount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoImg 

Copy-Item -Force -Recurse -Verbose 'C:\ESD\Deployment\sources\install.esd' 'C:\ESD\install.esd'
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my script I want PS to read whatever the name of the file is in the "Windows ISO" directory and use that file instead of hard coding the filename "Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso"

```
$isoImg =  get-childitem -path "C:\ESD\Windows 10 ISO\*.iso" |select   -expandproperty fullname
```

You may run into issues,if you have multiple ISO files